# Check if a function output matches its input

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function to which I'm passing, one by one) elements of the array as a arguments. Output of a function is a string. How can I check if output of that function is the same as its argument (element of an array). Something like: if string produced by the function is the same as string from the array (function argument) do something else do something. Simplified cod example:

```
array=(one two three)

for x in ${array[*]}; do
  if [[ -z function $x ]]; then
    echo "${x}"
  fi
done
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Corrected description (hopefully it makes more sense now).

Comment: Even after reading your description, I have no idea what "exists in a function" means

Comment: @jordanm - sorry, I corrected the description of the problem.

Comment: @user2997549 your title says "check if a function argument is non-empty," yet your question suggests "check if a function output matches its input." Which do you want?

Comment: @cbuckley - you're right about the title, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want

```
if [[ "$x" == "$(function "$x")" ]]; then ...
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work as expected - "then" block is always skipped. On the other hand, when I swapped "==" for "-eq" then the "then" block is always executed - even when I know that in one case this test should fail and execute "else"...

Comment: Sounds like your function is not returning what you think it does, then.  The double quotes take care to preserve any whitespace (including newlines) inside the value, so if you are counting on that being normalized, that would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: In Bash, `[[` supports `-eq` for numeric comparison, while `==` performs string comparison.  If your values are integers, `-eq` is the correct operator to use.